# How to get the pov/neg percentage from nltk classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, classification, nltk, nltk-trainer

I have a normal classifier which I made from the nltk twittes, more on that in this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-sentiment-analysis-in-python-3-using-the-natural-language-toolkit-nltk

I want to get the positive/negative percentage of a sentence. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextBlob library for sentiment polarity. If you'd like, you'll investigate these sites:

1. [Planspace.org](https://planspace.org/20150607-textblob_sentiment/)
2. [Stackabuse.com](https://stackabuse.com/sentiment-analysis-in-python-with-textblob/)
3. [Towarddatascience.com](https://towardsdatascience.com/my-absolute-go-to-for-sentiment-analysis-textblob-3ac3a11d524)